# failed to compile debug in wxwidgets windows 10

Tags: c++, gcc, wxwidgets, tdm-mingw

I want to develop apps across multiple platform. I am new with wxwidgets. I want to compile debug but it produce an error. this is my command result. please help me. so far i've done apps using wpf mvvm c# but it can only be run in windows env. so i'm changing to c++ knowing that it can be compiled in any environment. please help me.

```
C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\build\msw>mingw32-make SHELL=CMD.exe -f makefile.gcc USE_XRC=1 BUILD=debug UNICODE=1 SHARED=1 MONOLITHIC=1 USE_OPENGL=1 VENDOR=cb CXXFLAGS="-fno-keep-inline-dllexport"
if not exist ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\mswud mkdir ..\..\lib\gcc_dll\mswud
g++ -c -o gcc_mswuddll\monodll_any.o -g -O0 -mthreads  -DHAVE_W32API_H -D__WXMSW__       -D_UNICODE  -I..\..\lib\gcc_dll\mswud -I..\..\include  -W -Wall -DWXBUILDING -I..\..\src\tiff\libtiff -I..\..\src\jpeg -I..\..\src\png -I..\..\src\zlib -I..\..\src\regex -I..\..\src\expat\lib -I..\..\src\stc\scintilla\include -I..\..\src\stc\scintilla\lexlib -I..\..\src\stc\scintilla\src -D__WX__ -DSCI_LEXER -DLINK_LEXERS -DwxUSE_BASE=1 -DWXMAKINGDLL   -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy  -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -MTgcc_mswuddll\monodll_any.o -MFgcc_mswuddll\monodll_any.o.d -MD -MP ../../src/common/any.cpp
In file included from C:/TDM-GCC-32/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/type_traits:35:0,
                 from ..\..\include/wx/strvararg.h:25,
                 from ..\..\include/wx/string.h:46,
                 from ..\..\include/wx/any.h:19,
                 from ../../src/common/any.cpp:18:
C:/TDM-GCC-32/lib/gcc/mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
 #error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
  ^
In file included from ..\..\include/wx/string.h:46:0,
                 from ..\..\include/wx/any.h:19,
                 from ../../src/common/any.cpp:18:
..\..\include/wx/strvararg.h:350:18: error: 'is_enum' in namespace 'std' does not name a template type
     typedef std::is_enum<T> is_enum;
                  ^
..\..\include/wx/strvararg.h:354:54: error: 'is_enum' was not declared in this scope
     enum { value = wxFormatStringSpecifierNonPodType<is_enum::value>::value };
                                                      ^
..\..\include/wx/strvararg.h:354:68: error: template argument 1 is invalid
     enum { value = wxFormatStringSpecifierNonPodType<is_enum::value>::value };
                                                                    ^
makefile.gcc:6428: recipe for target 'gcc_mswuddll\monodll_any.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [gcc_mswuddll\monodll_any.o] Error 1

C:\wxWidgets-3.0.2\build\msw>
```

Comment: It seems as wxWidgets have been misconfigured and missed to add the `-std=c++11` flag.

Comment: `file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard` -- seem like that is the first problem to address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you been following the usual build instructions without any changes? Something exceedingly strange is happening, as `HAVE_TYPE_TRAITS` is somehow defined for you (look at the condition in the file `wx/strvararg.h` just above the line that the error points you to), yet this shouldn't be the case with the unmodified wxWidgets sources because it's only defined when using C++11, i.e. when `__cplusplus >= 201103L`, yet the compiler you use (g++ 5.1) defines `__cplusplus` as `199711L` by default.

If you had tried to build it differently, e.g. using configure, you must clean everything before building it again, i.e. just destroy the entire source directory and re-expand the archive if you had downloaded it or do `git clean -fdx` if you had cloned the Git repository.

Comment: i follow the instruction on [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KM8krlBWw7o) .

Comment: I _strongly_ recommend following the instructions in `docs/msw/install.txt` (or `install.md` in more recent wxWidgets versions) rather than in random 5 year old videos.

Comment: i knew it the manual should be there but alas hey thank you for helping me out. let me try it one more time.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the C++ standard to 11. Add `-std=c++11` to your compile command line (I didn't paste the whole line as it's very long.):

```
mingw32-make SHELL=CMD.exe -f makefile.gcc -std=c++11 USE_XRC=1 BUILD=debug U...
```

Comment: I'm sorry I kinda lost here. can you help me through? @SurvivalMachine

Comment: @Mace I added a bit about where to put the parameter in my answer.

Comment: This won't work at all, `-std=c++11` is not a make option. You need to add it inside `CXXFLAGS` if you really want to pass it to the compiler.